# Refresh DIV before heavy computation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, refresh

This keeps bugging me and although there's a lot of "Refresh DIV with jQuery" questions out there, none addresses (haven't found it, that is) this simple matter : how do I refresh (visual aspect) a DIV before doing some heavy lifting calculations? The idea is simple, I'm creating a big chart with D3 that takes a couple of seconds to generate and I want to be able to put an animated gif in overlay *before* computation and remove it after. Something like :

```
$("#test").empty();
$("#test").text("Should be seen while waiting");
for (var i=1;i<2000000000;i++) {
    //Draw heavy SVG in #test that takes time
}
$("#test").empty();
$("#test").text("Ready");
$("#test").css("color", "red");
```

Simple, but I haven't been able to do it thus far : the "Should be seen while waiting" never appears :(

A simple Fiddle here demonstrates the behaviour : http://jsfiddle.net/StephMatte/q29Gy/

I tried using setTimeout and jQuery's .delay() in 3 different browsers, but to no avail.

Thanx for any input.

Comment: Actually (i think) the code above will really execute the line `$("#test").text("Should be seen while waiting");`, but since it's too fast the display will display the 'Ready' text already.

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/q29Gy/4/, I have updated your jsfiddle and simulated a process requiring some seconds.

Comment: The way I understand it, that actually does nothing more than wait for 10 seconds, right? I'm currently looking at "callback functions", which I beleive is what you were pointing me at, but I'm not sure I understand. Could you modify the Fiddle so that there's actual computational work going on in between two changes of content in the DIV?

Comment: Hi, I've udpated the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/q29Gy/5/. What I did was request a json file and display the result. I couldn't find a bigger json file, so this will execute in just a little time. But on my end I can see the changing of the text from `Loading...` to `Ready`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But by looking at your previous code, I figured out I was simply using the wrong syntax for my setTimeout(). I'll post my "answer" below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was simply using the wrong syntax with setTimeout().

This did the trick :

```
$("#test").text("Is seen while generating heavy SVG");

setTimeout(function(){build_chart();}, 100);

$("#test").empty();
```

10ms wasn't enough, but 100ms is enough for the DIV to show its new content before going into heay computation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
box = $("<div>", {'id': 'box'});
$("#test").append(box);

$("#box").text("Should be seen while waiting");
for (var i=1;i<2000000000;i++) {
//Draw heavy SVG in #test that takes time
}
$("#box").remove();
$("#test").text("Ready");
$("#test").css("color", "red");`
```

Comment: I don't understand what that's suppose to change/do. Although it does hide the initial TEST in the DIV, it doesn't display "Should be seen while waiting". To investiguate, maybe, but not a solution, unfortunately.